# Cannot resolve method 'writeJson(java.lang.String, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)'

Tags: java

when I use IDEA,my code is wrong and note the information above and I have tried these methods:add the plugin named Lombok,add tomcat and add jsp_api.jar and servlet_api.jar.And to my sorrow,I still can not solve the problem.help,please.

```
package com.zlt.controller;

import cn.hutool.core.util.StrUtil;
import cn.hutool.crypto.SecureUtil;
import com.zlt.common.Constast;
import com.zlt.entity.JsAdmin;
import com.zlt.service.AdminService;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
if (StrUtil.equals(username, jsAdmin.getAdmin_name())&&StrUtil.equals(password, jsAdmin.getAdmin_pass())){
       writeJson("校验成功",resp);
    }
```

there are my code.

Comment: IDEA's runtime environment should be set to a Tomcat Server. Check that

Comment: I already set it,but the bug still there.

Comment: problem solved:Finally,I find the method writeJson come from the superclass and I forget writing it in the superclass!

Comment: glad you solved it mate!